# Iterating through images in folder path

Tags: python

If I have:

```
flags = ['australia.png', 'canada.png', 'newzealand.png', 'uk.png', 'usa.png']
```

and if these images are in some folder called "flags", how can I set the path to that folder to iterate through them?

Comment: `path = 'flags'`?

Comment: It's not clear to me what difficulty you were facing when trying to do this.

Comment: i have a loop: for flag in flags:(flags being the list)

plot the flag on a graph according to x and y axis and it works fine when the images are in the same folder where the code is, but my problem is, when i put the images of the flags in a folder. it doesnt work

Comment: can i set the path in the "flags" list directly to the folder? as in flags = ['flags/australia.png'] ? is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the path to the flags folder which can be done using the `os` module. This will be more robust and portable than adding them as strings.

```py
import os

flag_folder = '/path/to/flags'
flags = ['australia.png', 'canada.png', 'newzealand.png', 'uk.png', 'usa.png']

for filename in flags:
    flag_path = os.path.join(flag_folder, filename)
    # do something with flag_path
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want something to happen just when the images are in the flags folder:

```
import os

path = '.../flags/'
for flag in flags:
    if os.path.exists(path + flag):
        *do something*
```